# Extracting images from rosbag

Tags: ros, rosbag, image-view, extract-images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to extract images from a rosbag file with video, following the instructions here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data

I edited the roslaunch file for my specific files and it says that it's saving images apparently, but I have no idea where they're going. They're not in the directory I ran the command from, they're not in the image_view package directory, and I tried using locate to find them but I couldn't find them that way either. I tried looking at the source of extract_images.cpp but I don't see why it's not working since I thought cvSaveImage should probably save it into the current directory if a full path isn't specified. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9652/extracting-images-from-rosbag/) by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2011-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

D'oh, I found out that it put them in the ROS_HOME directory, which happens to be ~/.ros/. Did not realize this. Hope this helps someone else later.

---

Originally posted by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) with karma: 307 on 2011-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2